# How do I wait for an API response before my template tries to print the data?

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to print venue.city from my API response. My code works but it attempts to print venue.city when the page loads, this is giving a console error "Cannot read property 'city' of null".

How can I print my API response of a single Venue without getting this console error?

I have looked at the Vue lifecycle (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks), I have tried v-if and some other stuff that I found googling but nothing seems to work.

```
<template>
    <div class="venue">
        <div>
            test: {{ venue.city }}
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        name: "Venue",
        data() {
            return {
                venue: null
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.$route.params.id);
            axios.get("http://localhost:8080/venues/" + this.$route.params.id)
                .then(response => (this.venue = response.data))
                .catch(error => (console.log(error)));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the most reliable way to do it is to handle the states internally. This provides error handling and loading feedback.

In my real world apps, I usually use enumarate the states and use vuex to handle remote data and the load states are part of vuex too, but here is a simpler example using your code.

```html
<template>
  <div class="venue" v-if="loadState === 'DONE'">
    <div>test: {{ venue.city }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="error-message" v-else-if="loadState === 'ERROR'">
    Ooops. Something happened
  </div>
  <div class="loading-message" v-else>
    Loading...
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "Venue",
  data() {
    return {
      venue: null,
      loadState: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$route.params.id);
    this.loadState = 'LOADING';
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/venues/" + this.$route.params.id)
      .then(response => {
        this.venue = response.data;
        this.loadState = 'DONE';
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.loadState = 'ERROR';
        console.log(error)
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a nice implementation and it worked. Learned some new things from this!

Answer (score 0):

Vue has a lifecycle hook similar to the mounted, that is beforeMounted, that basically allows you to do something before the template is rendered, see below:

```
beforeMounted () {
  console.log(this.$route.params.id);
  axios.get("http://localhost:8080/venues/" + this.$route.params.id)
    .then(response => (this.venue = response.data))
    .catch(error => (console.log(error)));
}
```

You can also use a loading variable that updates in your then and catch, and then you conditional display the template based on that loading variable, like this:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <div v-if="loading">loading...</div>
  <template v-else>
    <div class="venue" v-if="loadState === 'DONE'">
      <div>test: {{ venue.city }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="error-message" v-else-if="loadState === 'ERROR'">
      Ooops. Something happened
    </div>
    <div class="loading-message" v-else>
      Loading...
    </div>
   </template>
 </div>
</template>
```

Then in your js:

```
beforeMounted () {
  console.log(this.$route.params.id);
  axios.get("http://localhost:8080/venues/" + this.$route.params.id)
    .then(response => (){
      this.loading = false
    })
    .catch(error => () {
      this.loading = false
    });
}
```

Hope it helps :)